# Dúvida sobre compilação em C/C++

Tags: c, c++, compilação

Comecei a estudar sobre compilação de múltiplos arquivos e me surgiu uma dúvida. Quando criamos um novo header, temos que criar um outro arquivo com a implementação dos protótipos contidos na header, criar o objeto e compilar tudo junto. Porém, quando incluímos bibliotecas padrão, como por exemplo a `stdio.h`, não necessitamos criar o arquivo objeto dele e nem compilar ele junto. Porque e como isso é feito?? As funções já são implementadas dentro destas bibliotecas padrão?

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

> **TL/DR:** Seu compilador / linkeditor está encontrando as dependências que você incluiu (e.g., `stdlib.h`) em alguma biblioteca no caminho padrão. Conforme as opções de compilação / linkedição, a biblioteca está sendo incluída dinamicamente ou estaticamente.

Sua pergunta tem uma reposta simples, porém não é possível falar sobre o que acontece sem rever uma série de conceitos:

## Bibliotecas dinâmicas vs estáticas

Bibliotecas em C / C++ podem ser linkadas estaticamente ou dinamicamente.

Em um simplificação grosseira, linkedição estática produz um executável independente com uma cópia da biblioteca; ou seja, você acaba com um executável maior contendo o binário da sua aplicação e da biblioteca. Caso você necessite alterar a biblioteca terá que recompilar o seu aplicativo para incluir as novas alterações.

Em oposição, linkedição dinâmica produz artefatos independentes. Uma biblioteca compartilhada (geralmente `.so` em sistemas *NIX e `.dll` no Windows) é carrega em *load time* ou *run time*. Grosseiramente a aplicação que referencia uma biblioteca dinâmica contém uma "tabela de símbolos" indicando dependências externas, quando alguma dessas dependências (e.g., uma função qualquer) é requisitada ela é "carregada em memória" (os detalhes do "algoritmo" que determina como e qual biblioteca deve ser "carregada" são complexos, não quero entrar nesse mérito).

A vantagem das bibliotecas dinâmicas é que uma única biblioteca pode ser compartilhada entre vários executáveis; adicionalmente as bibliotecas também podem ser atualizadas de forma independente (desde que seja mantida a compatibilidade binária). A desvantagem é que projetos complexos podem acabar com um grafo profundo de dependências, criando todo tipo de problema (incompatibilidade de versões, inclusão acidental de versões legadas da biblioteca, necessidade de fazer *backport* de *fixes* de segurança para versões legadas, etc, etc, etc).

### Templates

Além de protótipos de funções, structs, classes e enumerações (parte da "assinatura / interface" de determinada biblioteca), *templates* são incluídos nos cabeçalhos. Em tempo de compilação / linkedição são geradas versões específicas das construções parametrizadas (e.g., uma versão com `int` e outra com `float` de um template da função) embarcadas no binário da aplicação. É por isso que em alguns compiladores o tamanho do binário cresce significamente quando você utiliza, por exemplo, a [std](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library).

### Como o linkeditor encontra uma biblioteca

Como o seu linkeditor encontra uma biblioteca? Grosseiramente ele faz uma busca no *path* (caminho) em que bibliotecas são disponibilizadas. [A resposta do @pmg](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68098/100) menciona a `libc`; o linkeditor pode encontrar uma implementação como a `libc.so` ou `msvcrt.lib` em uma infinidade de locais por uma infinidade de regras  (flags passadas para o linkeditor, variáveis de ambiente como `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, diretórios padrão como `/usr/lib`, diretório atual da aplicação, etc, etc, etc). As regras geralmente variam com o sistema operacional e a *stack* de *build*.

### Então o que acontece de verdade quando incluo bibliotecas como `stdlib.h`, `iostream`, etc?

Em aplicações suficientemente complexas, as bibliotecas necessárias são localizadas e ocorre uma combinação de linkedição dinâmica e estática, bem como instanciação / expansão de templates. 
Enquanto boa parte dos compiladores vão, por padrão, fazer o possível para linkar bibliotecas dinamicamente, uma parte do código das bibliotecas acaba sendo diretamente ou indiretamente copiado / expandido dentro do executável.

Linkeditores geralmente são capazes de reportar tudo o que foi linkado estaticamente e dinamicamente (e.g., [`gcc -Wl --verbose`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23131842/664577)). Adicionalmente, ferramentas como [`ldd`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ldd.htm) e [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) conseguem listar dependências.

Answer (score 1):

A compilacao das funcoes que tem os prototipos, por exemplo, em `<stdio.h>` foi feita por outra pessoa noutro computador.
Essa pessoa meteu esses objectos compilados numa biblioteca e quando instalaste o teu Sistema Operativo (ou compilador) tambem instalaste essa biblioteca. A biblioteca em questao chama-se `"libc"` e, se nao disseres nada em contrario ao compilares um programa teu o compilar automaticamente inclui essa biblioteca.

Nota que essa mesma biblioteca tem o resultado da compilacao de muitas outras funcoes alem das que tem prototipo em `<stdio.h>`.

Por razoes historicas, as funcoes com prototipo em `<math.h>` nao se costuman adicionar a biblioteca `libc`, mas sim a biblioteca `libm`. Alguns compiladores nao pesquisam na biblioteca `libm` quando compilam, por isso, para esses compiladores, 'e necessario indicar essa biblioteca

```
gcc main.c -lm
```

O `-l` da invocacao do gcc, indica ao compilador para pesquisar na biblioteca especificada, precedida de "lib".